# java.net.MalformedURLException in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to execute a GET request, but Intellij keeps refusing to let me do it!
Here is my code...

```java
String checkUrl = "https://proxycheck.io/v2/" + event.getAddress().toString();
URL url = new URL(checkUrl);
```

For no reason AT ALL, Intellij throwed out [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1xXI.png).
I've never had this error in Intellij nor do I know what is wrong with my URL! And yes, I have tried a domain like `https://google.com` but it still throws out [that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2IbW.png).

Comment: Okay, so I have added try catch into the code and it doesn't warning the error any more, but I'm worried that it will break in production, it will just throws out the error not on my IDE, but the client...

Comment: How you handle the exception is up to you, your needs and your program. There are many tutorials about that if you want to research that.